# Good book on advanced trig

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

Is there a good book on trig that covers the geometry of the trig functions and how they relate to waves and SHM.  I've already taken calculus, so I'm looking for more of a Trig 2 type book -- if such a thing exists.

Another interesting topic a Trig 2 book might cover (and that I'd be interested in) is trigonometry in non-Euclidean spaces: spherical trig, hyperbolic trig, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The non-standard trig books I know of are:

[**Trigonometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639144) by Israel M. Gelfand and Alexander Shen

> This might be too low level for you now, but it's cheap and worth taking a look at anyway.

[**Elementary and Advanced Trigonometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007QBB0HI) by Kenneth Sielke Miller and John Breffni Walsh

> This is probably the best fit for you in my opinion, but the book is not in many libraries, so to look at a copy you'll probably have to either buy it or use interlibrary loan. (*UPDATE about 4 years later* --- I was was searching to see whether a print copy of this book exists for purchase, and I discovered that a digital copy of the book [is now freely available](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.141418).)

[**Advanced Trigonometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486432297) by Clement Vavasor Durell and Alan Robson

> A bit more advanced than Miller/Walsh, plus the emphasis is on pure mathematics whereas Miller/Walsh is more suited for an upper level engineering student. (*UPDATE about 4.5 years later* --- FYI, there is a 380-page solutions manual for this book, the details of which I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669754/reference-request-book-for-trigonometry-and-geometry/1670481#1670481).)

[**A Treatise on Plane and Advanced Trigonometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486441776) by Ernest William Hobson

> This is more advanced than Durell/Robson, and is also directed mainly towards pure mathematics.