# Reference Request: Book for Trigonometry and Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I found myself uncomfortable with sophisticated geometry problems. SO I want book which includes deep knowledge of geometry and teaches user how to use Trigonometry in smart way to solve geometric problems.
Also is there any book which can provides almost everything on geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best and most complete books on geometry is Marcel Berger's [*Geometry I, II*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540116583) (translated from French). It presupposes an acquaintance with basic undergraduate mathematics (abstract and linear algebra, topology and some analysis). There is a separate book with exercises.

A good book with more modest prerequisites is Pedoe's [*Geometry: A Comprehensive Course*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CB2MJ8G)

Deltheil and Caire's [*Géométrie*](http://www.gabay-editeur.com/epages/300555.sf/fr_FR/?ObjectPath=/Shops/300555/Products/346) and [*Compléments de géométrie*](http://www.gabay-editeur.com/epages/300555.sf/fr_FR/?ObjectPath=/Shops/300555/Products/347) are classics.

Answer (score 3):

See Durell/Robson's [**Advanced Trigonometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486432297), especially the first two chapters. By the way, there is a very complete solutions manual by Durell and Robson for this text (see below) that you might be able to get through interlibrary loan. (I'm surprised Dover publications didn't reprint the solutions manual when they reprinted the book.)

[**Key to Advanced Trigonometry**](http://www.worldcat.org/title/key-to-advanced-trigonometry/oclc/680098740), George Bell and Sons, 1930, 380 pages.

Reviewed by Charles John Agnew Trimble, **Mathematical Gazette** 15 #215 (October 1931), p. 480. (Online at [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3606232) and at [cambridge.org](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/key-to-advanced-trigonometry-by-durell-c-v-and-robson-a-pp-380-15s-1930-bell/7D6635669BE122946CEEDEE9653F5FE3).)

Comment: Durell and Robson's book can be found here: http://www.knowledge-dojo.com/ Only the first two chapters (of 14) actually seem to deal with geometry. By "advanced trigonometry" they mainly seem to mean "complex numbers," which I think was typical nomenclature in schools at their time.