# Is there a "rigorous" book on "complete" trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request

By rigorous and complete I mean a book that contains proofs to all trig identities and formulas as well as those of hyperbolic geometry. I know there are proofs to most of these around the internet but is there a specific book or website that accomplishes this? Also, a geometric approach would be preferable.

Comment: See my answers to [Good book on advanced trig](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838514/good-book-on-advanced-trig) AND [Reference Request: Book for Trigonometry and Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669754/reference-request-book-for-trigonometry-and-geometry), and also [this (admittedly biased) google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trigonometry%22+%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22Hobson%22&filter=0).

Comment: Here are three other older books, besides those I cited above, that are pretty complete: [**A System of Plane and Spherical Trigonometry**](https://archive.org/details/asystemplaneand00wilsgoog) by Richard Wilson (1831); [**A Treatise on Plane Trigonometry**](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00caseuoft) by John Casey (1888); [**Éléments de Trigonométrie Plane et Sphérique**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000475054) [[copy at google-books](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Qg5iGbPfLsC)] by Émile Gelin (1888; most complete of these three).

Comment: E. W. Hobson, _A Treatise on Plane Trigonometry,_ Cambridge University Press, 1891. $\qquad$