# What are some best books for learning inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, inverse-function

I have learnt elementary trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions. But the materials in my textbook isn't enough for me to gain a deeper understanding. I want to book that provides proofs of various **inverse trigonometric formulas** and related stuffs. I have already tried some books eg., [S. L Loney's Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9351761754) and some others. I want a book that provides proof for $\tan^{−1}x+\tan^{−1}y=π+\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1−xy}$ when $xy>1$ and related inverse trigonometric formulas.
Thank you!

Comment: See [Good book on advanced trig](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838514/13130).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Based on the question I think these books mostly covers non-Euclidean spaces: spherical trig, hyperbolic trig.

Comment: The question suggested spherical trig and hyperbolic trig, but the books in the answer do not appear to be "mostly" about that. You could actually take a look before deciding.

Comment: *Based on the question I think these books mostly covers non-Euclidean spaces* ---The books in my answer there were not selected for the other OP's additional request (although 3 of the 4 books I mentioned cover a fair amount about hyperbolic trig. functions). The books I gave there, at least (a different) 3 of them, are very well known and frequently cited here for math contest level trig. Incidentally, freely available copies of various editions of Hobson's book are on the internet ([here](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs), for example).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I have looked upon the Hobson's book but couldn't find the proof of the exact formula I have mentioned above (the formulas in page 55 isn't what I was looking for). I wanted something more dedicated to this specific topic.

Comment: See also the books mentioned at [Is there a "rigorous" book on "complete" trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771222/13130) Regarding "I wanted something more dedicated to this specific topic", I don't think you'll find anything better than the books in the links I've given, but there might be some expository papers or unpublished manuscripts. If I come across any, I'll let you know.

Comment: Just now, by accident, I happened to see a relatively complete discussion of the inverse tangent identity you asked about. See pp. 134-135 in **The Elements of Plane Trigonometry** (1892) by Rawdon Levett (1843-1923) and Charles Davison (1858-1940) -- [internet archive](https://archive.org/details/elementsofplanet00leveuoft/page/134/mode/2up) and [google-books](https://books.google.com/books?id=S2A7AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA134). You'll need to look somewhere earlier in the book to see what their convention is for the use of upper case 'T' and lower case 't' in the tangent function designations.

Comment: Thank you @DaveL.Renfro.

Comment: In case you're still interested in book references, I just came across one that might be of interest. See pages 38-39 & 193-205 (and maybe pages 92 & 394) in [**A Problem Book In Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/v.-a.-krechmar-a-problem-book-in-algebra-mir-1978) by Krechmar (1978). Although this isn't a traditional textbook, complete solutions are provided for all the problems, in particular for the problems involving inverse trigonometric functions on the pages I cited.