# Learning $\arcsin, \arccos, \arctan$ - how to?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, inverse-function

Sorry for asking such question.

I have a very basic understanding of $\arcsin, \arccos, \arctan$ functions. I do know how their graph looks like and not much more beyond that.

**Calculate:**
[image: Tasks]

Which specific *keywords* should I google to learn how to solve the following tasks? I think those aren't equations (googling 'cyclometric equations' was a dead end). Perhaps you would like to share with some link to a beginner-friendly learning source?

Thank you.

Comment: inverse trigonometric functions is what I would call them

Comment: also a lot of them just require the compound angle formula or some rearrangment to make them a lot easier

Comment: Thanks. Anything more specific than 'inverse trigonometric functions' to google? I believe it's a fairly wide subject.

Comment: "cyclometric" is the old name for the inverse trig functions. Any basic book should have sections on how to evaluate these.

Comment: these are more simple but a start: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/AlgebraTrigReview/InverseTrig.aspx

Comment: I've never heard of "cyclometric equations" used anywhere before now. If you want to study trigonometry (or anything up until pre-university, you can try using Khan academy).

Comment: if you ask specifically about 1 of those questions that you struggle with people will also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good reference as summary from Wikipedia are

- [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities)

and also

- [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Some exercises given requires only to calculate the value for the functions at some point, other else are more tricky and you need to acquire a deeply understanding of the matter.

Refer also to the related

- [Reference Request: Book for Trigonometry and Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669754/505767)
- [Good book on advanced trig](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838514/505767)

Comment: That should help, thanks.

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask for any exercise in particular! Bye

Comment: I would, but unless I made any significant progress myself, I don't think anyone will solve that for me. :)

Comment: That’s nice but in case of doubt I would happy to check that with you. Bye

Answer (score 2):

I would say there are three things you are expected to do on this list.  One is to know the trig functions of special angles, so for 4 you should know that $\tan \frac \pi 4=1,$ so $\arctan 1=\frac \pi 4$  Watch out for the ranges specified for the inverse trig functions.  Second is that $\sin(\arcsin (x))=x$.  When you have $\arcsin (\sin(x))$ you may be shifted by factors of $\pi$.  Finally when you have $\sin(\arccos(\frac 13))$ draw a right triangle with $\cos$ of one angle $\frac 13$, so it is a $1-\sqrt 8-3$ triangle and find the sine of the angle, here $\frac 13\sqrt 8$.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I understood everything except for: "When you have arcsin(sin(x)) you may be shifted by factors of π". Would you give a little bit more insight on this?

Comment: The range of $\arcsin$ is defined as $[-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$, so if we are asked for $\arcsin(\sin(\frac {9\pi}4))$ the answer is $\frac \pi 4,$ not $\frac {9 \pi}4$

Comment: Those indeed are the tricky questions which I was referring to!

Comment: I don't know which post should I accept, since you both helped me a lot. I'll do a random.org roll.

Answer (score 2):

**This lecture has been particularly helpful on understanding the subject:**

https://academics.utep.edu/Portals/1788/CALCULUS%20MATERIAL/4_7%20INVERSE%20TRIG%20FNS.pdf