# Seeking a trigonometry book that explains everything in depth

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

> I'm searching for a trigonometry book that explains everything in depth. I mean, in completely depth, explaining every single thing about trigonometry (a.k.a. explains from where comes each trigonometric ratio, how I can prove that it works...).

I found a pdf of Gelfand's book and read first pages of definition of sine, but it seemed to me that he doesn't explain everything. Maybe, he just don't want to start briskly and will explain more in depth in the following chapters.

Any suggestion? Do you think Gelfand actually can satisfy me?

Comment: See [Good book on advanced trig](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838514/13130).

Comment: https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the phrase "*completely depth, explaining every single thing*" is not applicable for any book. If so happens, then there is nothing left beyond that. Also there is no book that completely explain everything in its content. However I am providing some references those may help you a lot.

$1.~~$ "Trigonometry" by Michael Corral

$2.~~$ "A Treatise on Trigonometry" by James Edward Oliver, George William Jones, Lucian Augustus Wait

$3.~~$ "Plane Trigonometry" by S. L. Loney

$4.~~$ "Conceptual Trigonometry" by Chandra Shekhar Kumar

Answer (score 2):

[Sidney Luxton Loney (free at Google books)](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Sidney_Luxton_Loney_Plane_Trigonometry?id=tZsBAAAAYAAJ) has an excellent book that is geared to advanced students; it has a lot of geometric proofs and extensive exercises.  It even goes into complex numbers with incredible detail.

I have Gelfand's book as well, but I think that's more for high school and early college students.